# Unable to load static resource on client orgs. when manage package is installed

Tags: visualforce

I have a managed package. After installation it on summer 16 orgs the static resources are not served. It is working fine with spring 16 and pervious orgs.

Below error is shown on browser console :
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'URL'. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'URL' is therefore not allowed access.

Does anybody know whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

is it due to this?

https://partners.salesforce.com/partnerAlert?id=a033A00000FLgB7QAL

If so, looks like you'll need to rebuild your managed package to get Salesforce to annotate font reference URLs as indicated in the article

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: No @MarkX let me show you with example : please install [this](https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04tB0000000Fsvu) package. The page /apex/testpackagepage needs to open A bootstrap Modal but due to static resource issue it is not opening.